# How to match something, which may or may not be available in regex?

Tags: regex

I found this little thing online `(.*)((?::))((?:[0-9]+))$` which will split an IP address and port.

eg.

```sh
[ab:cd::0]:22
host.domain.com:443
1.2.3.4:22
```

However, it requires this format and does not care for other formats.

Due to this I made a minor change `(.*)((?::))((?:[0-9]+))?$`, which will then only include port if available.

Now, there are three kinds of formats available for URIs:

```sh
host.domain.com
host.domain.com: 
host.domain.com:port
```

I am kind of lost here. because while adding a `?` for the second group `(.*)((?::))?((?:[0-9]+))?$` the whole regex is eaten up by the greedy `(.*)`.

Any idea how to deal with this problem in a good way?

BR

Patrik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
^(.*?)(?:(:)([0-9]*))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pe1snf/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?:(:)([0-9]*))?` - an optional sequence of

  - `(:)` - Group 2: a colon
  - `([0-9]*)` - Group 3: zero or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor! I looked up (.*?) and the ? seems to mean non-greedy in this case (according to commonly used nomenclature). This should be the same as explained by you Wiktor, but I just want to add the phrase 'non-greedy' here to simplify for others finding this post.